# How to convert a histogram to a PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I know this may be an easy question, but due to lack of math knowledge I do not know the answer. Would you please explain to me with a simple example that how can I find PDF from a histogram. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Maybe this belongs under the LaTeX exchange?

Comment: This is a basic question about probability!

Comment: You can generate a .PDF in LaTeX or any TeX distribution really.  Or does PDF stand for Probabilistic Distribution Function?

Comment: Please see the question tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a nutshell - you cannot. Histogram does not contain enough information regarding the distribution to obtain it.

You can (very roughly) estimate it by a discrete pdf, where $pdf(x) = \frac{histogram(bin(x))}{\sum_{bin} histogram(bin)}$, where $bin(x)$ is the bin containing $x$, and $histogram(y)$ is amount of points in the $y$'th bin.

Although if you have access to the samples that were used to create a histogram you can use density estimation techniques, for example kernel density estimation.

Comment: Yes I have the samples and I want to estimate their probabilities.

Comment: Does the width of bars play any role in the value of histogram(y)?

Comment: The wider the bars (containing more values) the less correct the estimation. This is the only correlation I can give.

If you have samples, then you should actually ask how to retrive the distribution given samples, not given histogram. Histogram is **worse** representation then raw samples. If you do not know what kind of distribution to expect, try the **kernel density estimation** (numerical method). If you know that this is gaussian (or a mixture of $k$ gaussians) - then you can fit the gaussian with some simple optimization techniques.

Comment: Thanks I will try to find another way to estimate the PDF as you said.

Answer (score 1):

For each bin in the histogram, the probability of that value is the number of counts in the bin divided by the total number of counts in the histogram.

Added:  if you want, you can then try to find a distribution that "looks like" the histogram.  If your histogram looks like a normal distribution, you could **assume the distribution is normal** and do a fit to find the parameters, then claim that is the PDF.

Comment: Just a question, does the width of bars play any role?

Comment: I am assuming the width of all the bars is the same.  You then have a discrete PDF, centered at the center of each bar.  By making a histogram, you have lost the information of where each event is within the bar, so this is the best you can do.

Comment: what do you mean by " the information of where each event is within the bar"?

Comment: If you have a bin that runs from $0$ to $1$, an event that is counted in that bin could have had value $0.1$ or it could have had value $0.9$.  If you had the raw data, you could use it (like your other question) to improve your estimate of the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to give answer with an example.

% Matlab code to get the pdf from set of samples

**n = 1e5;**                   % Total number of samples
**x = 2*rand(1,n)-1;**        % generate uniform distribution samples
**b = 0.1;**       % bin width, should be lesser to get more accurate PDF
**[h,k] = hist(x,[-5:b:5]);**
**plot(k,h/n/k);**

Note that you should also devide the h by total samples and bin width.

Comment: I'm not a Matlab user. Could you explain what is h/n/k? What is h and k? And where is the pdf? It must be a function.